# Decimales Grandes en Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

quiero saber que tipo de dato en usar para números que pueden ser decimales pero muy alto, como 10'000'000,123. Lo voy a usar en Mysql, Java y Javascript. Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: ¿Has investigado un poco el asunto? ¿Qué has encontrado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para **MYSQL** existe el tipo de dato [Decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)  `decimal(x, y)`, donde `x` es la cantidad de numero a tratar incluyendo los decimales, mientras que `y` son la cantidad de numeros de la parte decimal, para el ejemplo que muestras el campo seria:

```
campo DECIMAL(11, 3)
```

De esta forma podemos manejar `11` numeros de los cuales 3 son de la parte decimal lo que nos da un rango desde `-99,999,999.999 hasta 99,999,999.999.`

Respecto sobre Java  recomendaria hacer uso de [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) al menos a mi me ha dado mejores resultados.

Y en `Javascript` no deberias tener problemas de igual manera en github hay varias bibliotecas para el uso de `BigDecimal` con sus funciones para hacer operaciones con ellas.

Comment: Gracias, si habia investigado algo, pero lo encontraba un poco confuso, ahora si me quedo claro el campo decimal.